# How to make two operations atomic in asp.net webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, webforms, ado.net

In an asp.net webform page, I need to do two operations.

- Insert a record into the database.
- Store an image related to that    record in the file system of the
  server

What I need is to make both actions atomic in this case both of the operations should succeed or none of them. Since the second operation is not a database operation I think we can't use ADO.Net transactions. So how we can make both atomic?

**UPDATE** The scenario is that the database table has an ID column. I have to insert the database record first, taking its ID and renaming the file with the id and then saving it to the server.

Comment: You can't achieve that with 100% certainty.

Comment: Try to save file inside db transaction, rollback it if save failed.

Comment: @Alex please write a code snippet. I think we can't achieve it this way.

Comment: If you store the path to the image in the database then you can achieve this with a transaction.

Comment: @Alex What happens if the database commit fails? _Now you have a file on the file system without a matching DB record._ What if you then try and delete the file but the file system crashes beforehand (and comes back up in 10 minutes with the file still there)? What do you do?

Comment: @mjwills that is the point.

Comment: I know @ElhamKohestani . Hence my first comment. You can try using compensating transactions or other techniques, but they are all relatively complex and very unlikely to be 100% reliable all of the time.

Comment: @mjwills, good points. So, let's think out of scope, what could be done? How about save image into blob together with a record, so both failed or both succeed. And then, as a next step - save blob to file on server.

Comment: @Alex due to the disadvantages of storing blobs in the database and based on my business need I can't store the images in the database itself.

Comment: And if you fail saving the blob to the server, what do you do @Alex ?

Comment: @ElhamKohestani What **I** would do is store the file on the file system and then write to the DB. _You will get some level of orphaned files - which you could periodically scan for and cleanup (effectively a compensating transaction)._

Comment: @mjwills check the update.

Comment: It simply can't be done in a 100% reliable way, given that constraint. You could add a queue to increase reliability - but the queue could go down. etc etc. You should consider, rather than having the database define the filename, instead have the database store the filename that was generated outside of the database. Then my earlier suggestion will work fine.

Comment: Whatever solution you decide on, be clear on what should happen if the file system is down. And also be clear on what should happen in the database is down. And test both scenarios.

Comment: Assuming your database supports it, you can store the file inside the database instead of on the file system, and do both things in a single SQL Command (eliminating the need for an explicit transaction). Please note that storing files in the database does come with a minor performance penalty.

Comment: "due to the disadvantages of storing blobs in the database and based on my business need I can't store the images in the database itself"  Could you elaborate on this?  What are your disadvantages and business needs that prevent this being an option?

Comment: @Trevor the images have big sizes. There will be backup problems when the size of data grows in the database.